# iterate over list in R and store list

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of matrix/vector and would like to apply R functions and store the output as a list in a sequence of numbers. As am example: I have a vector x and would like to calcualte min,max,median,quantile and store it in a list every iteration,

```
outlist <- vector("list", 10)

for(p in seq(from=5, to=50, by=5))  {

  x <- c(rnorm(20)) 

  min <- min(x)
  max <- max(x)
  median <- median(x)
  quant <- quantile(x)

  outlist[[p]] <- list(c(min=min,max=max,median=median,quant=quant))

  print(p)
  }
```

The code above works fine, except that the output and has lots of "null" values . See below for the output from the program above, notice that 1 thru 4 is null and only in 5th iteration we start get the list output. This repeats for all the iteration. Can you please let me know how I should avoid null values in the output.

Below are my questions. How to ensure all the null values are not present and only sequence numbers (p=5,10,15,...,50) in the iteration are present.

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
       min        max     median   quant.0%  quant.25%  quant.50%  quant.75% quant.100% 
-2.1058435  2.8461767 -0.5227028 -2.1058435 -1.1500056 -0.5227028  0.1645680  2.8461767
```

In addition, how to create a matrix(vector) output for list with row name as the sequence example ?

```
       min        max     median   quant.0%  quant.25%  quant.50%  quant.75% quant.100% 
5  -2.1058435  2.8461767 -0.5227028 -2.1058435 -1.1500056 -0.5227028  0.1645680  2.8461767 
10 -0.7709128  2.2872216  0.1808006 -0.7709128 -0.1501660  0.1808006  0.8250730  2.2872216 
15 -2.3748713  2.0360717  0.2638579 -2.3748713 -0.2631081  0.2638579  0.6446657  2.0360717

and so on ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, if you are only assigning to items with an index of multiples of 5 what did you expect. Learn to use `seq_along` for index generation if you want "dense" values. 
`

Comment: You just want to remove the NULLs? `Filter(Negate(is.null), outlist)` or you want summary stats for each iteration? If the latter, why would you have the loop only do every 5th iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the list using the `foreach` package. The `foreach` function will return you a list and you can assign its names afterwards.

```
library(foreach)

vectorNames <- seq(from=5, to=50, by=5)

outlist <- foreach(p = vectorNames) %do% {

  x <- c(rnorm(20)) 

  min <- min(x)
  max <- max(x)
  median <- median(x)
  quant <- quantile(x)

  return(c(min=min,max=max,median=median,quant=quant))
}

names(outlist) <- vectorNames
```

Then, you can create the matrix using `do.call` and `rbind`.

```
outmatrix <- do.call(rbind, outlist)
outmatrix
```